# What is the subject of a survey called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

For example, the subject of an interview is an interviewee.

So, I was wondering what the subject of a survey might be.

Comment: Also 'survey subject'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

despite the fact that most of us are inundated with surveys and they most likely use such a word in their communication, all I can think of is:

**respondent**.

(all the obvious constructions just don't sound like they are used despite their 'correctness'.)

Comment: +1 Just want to note that this only works for surveys as in questionnaires. This doesn't work when the surveyed is a plot of land.

Comment: *Respondent* is the term that is used at the United States Census Bureau (my employer).

Comment: @Matt Ellen: neither would "interviewee" be fit for a plot of land. I think the question implied an animate object. But that begs the question indeed as to what word would suit inanimate object best.

Comment: @Benjamin see my answer :D

Comment: Usage as measured by Google hits: "survey respondent/s" (165K/2.3M), "survey participant/s" (125K/850K), "survey subject/s" (36K/103K hits, many bogus) and even the dubious "surveyee/s" (4K/10K). *survey subjects* (without quotes) gets 113M hits but I don't know how to disambiguate them.

Answer (score 2):

Since someone who conducts and survey is a *surveyor* then someone or something being surveyed is *the surveyed*.

Similarly to how the object of a *tormentor* is *the tormented*.

Comment: though it is not clear, I think the OP is not thinking of both 'someone answering a questionnaire' and 'plot of land being measured', just the first one. 'Surveyed' works for both, and is literally correct, but also sounds strange for both.

Answer (score 1):

Simply *subject of survey*. Or you can use *surveyed object*. There does not seem to be any one-word synonym for it. If you don't consider *survivor* as one :)

Answer (score 0):

The subject of survey, in a sense, is **surveyor**, but the best suited word or the subject I would use if I made a survey is **pollster**.